# Can we have two navigation flow in a single View in iPad?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I wanted to show two different Navigation flows for the user when the App is in use at the same time.

My Requirement is as below:

In a View based Application, I wanted to have two Table Views A and B (A at top and B at Bottom). When user selects a row in Table A, a detailed View is shown to user, by pushing another View Controller. At this point in time, the Navigation should happen only in case of the Top Level View and the bottom Table View should not have any effect on this.

And I should be able to do the same for Table View B.

**UPDATE:**

It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/

It is a replacement for UISplitViewController and has an option to do a horizontal split as well as set the size of the split so that you can make it look like what you have there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting iOS 5, you can use **UIViewController Containment**.  There is a good [WWDC 2011 video on the topic](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/implementing-uiviewcontroller-containment.html#implementing-uiviewcontroller-containment).

Otherwise, your only option is to add a "child" UIViewController's view to a "parent" UIViewController's view and manually pass the parent UIViewController delegate method invocations to the child.  For instance, here is a snippet from MGSplitViewController (mentioned by @Inafziger):

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.masterViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [self.detailViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```